# Как в декартовой системе координат найти вершину четырехугольника по трем вершинам и расстояниям?

Tags: математика, геометрия

В декартовой системе координат нужно найти вершину четырехугольника.
Известны координаты 3-ех вершин, расстояние от них до 4-ой вершины.
Пришел к системе уравнений, но не смог вынести "X" и "Y".

---

Сама система (теперь вообще не уверен, что это верная система, но это все, что я смог "нарыть"):

1. (x-Xa)^2+(y-Ya)^2=L1^2,
2. (x-Xb)^2+(y-Yb)^2=L2^2,
3. (x-Xc)^2+(y-Yc)^2=L3^2.

Соответственно известны: L1, L2, L3, Xabc, Yabc.

---

Само задание звучит примерно так:

> Имеется декартовая система координат в которой есть 3 статичных точки, 4-ая перемещается в плоскости, после каждого перемещения мне становится известна длинна отрезка от каждой из точек до 4-ой точки. Нужно найти координаты 4-ой точки.

Comment: От всех трех одно и то же расстояние?... 8-/

Comment: Нет, прошу прощения, L1,L2,L3

Comment: Ну, в общем случае решения нет...

Comment: То есть реализовать автоматический расчет невозможно? Может быть я не правильно понял задание, сейчас внесу в вопрос, как звучит задание

Comment: Только самом-самое первоначальное :)

Comment: Внес изменения в вопрос, может быть сейчас станет понятнее

Comment: Так ведь **в пространстве**, не **в плоскости**!

Comment: Примерно написал, допустил ошибку, 4-ая точка точно перемещается в плоскости

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ладно, если гарантированно в плоскости...

Для начала выполним перенос начала координат в точку A (хоть чуть-чуть упростить задачу). Тогда ваши координаты для B превращаются в

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тогда (xa==ya==0) первые два уравнения дают два решения (если дают :) - если расстояние между точками (xa,xb) и (ya,yb) больше L1+L2 - решений нет:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так у вас получаются 2 точки (одна для верхнего знака в ±, вторая - для нижнего; для перевода в прежнюю систему координат надо прибавить к x значение xa, к y - ya). Какая из точек верная (или система несовместна) - решаете из расстояния до третей точки.